# filter git commit history after sparse checkout

Tags: git

There are dozens of folders under git repo; but I work with one of them only. So, I don't want to know what's happening with projects under other folders.
I checked out a branch from remote with enabled sparse checkout and now I have only one folder locally; but I still can see full commits history when using gitk. I also see it when doing some changes during interactive rebase.

My question is: Whether it's possible to somehow clean (filter) commits history so that I saw only ones related to particular folder when rebasing? Idea is to work with the repo same way as if it contained only one folder.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to solution to work in console and different GUIs, or just in console?

Comment: @PetrHejda I use only console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For read operations, you can often get what you want by passing path options.

```
git log -- ./the_one_folder
```

or

```
gitk -- ./the_one_folder
```

But for operations that write, such as rebase, there is no general way to do what you describe.  If you commit everything to one big history, then that history is essentially a part of each commit.  So you have a commit that changes `the_one_folder`, even if its parent doesn't change anything in the same folder that parent is part of the commit and you can't do a rebase "as though it weren't there".

You could do a rebase that drops all the commits you don't care about, but then those commits are removed from the branch you're rebasing.  So basically you'd have to have a set of branches for your directory, and a set of branches for the next directory that the next guy works on, and on and on.

And once you do that, it starts to look like you should've put each project in its own repo.  And that's a fact.  In git, you shouldn't cram a bunch of projects into the same repo.  If you do sometimes correlate changes across projects, there are ways to deal with that; but it sounds like at least most of the time these are independent, so if you don't want a bunch of cluttered histories you should consider moving to separate repos.

There is a way to create a history of "just your project" - realizing that this is only really useful if you are indeed migrating to separate repos (or at least separate namespaced sets of refs, but that's just a more complicated way to do the same thing so why?) because once its done changes to the separate history will no longer be reflected in the combined history.

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter the_one_folder --prune-empty -- --all
```

Comment: It's clear that repo I work with built incorrectly; but unfortunately I have no influence on it. Thanks for you answer.