# git log filter with sparse checkout

Tags: git, git-log

I have a large project that I use sparse checkout to exclude one directory (which is quite large).  However, when I use git log, the commit in the directory that I already excluded with sparse checkout will show up, polluting my real interests.

The answer given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180781/filter-git-commit-history-after-sparse-checkout) by specifying one directory doesn't work for me since I need to exclude one directory but include many. I came from perforce where if I specify `...`, it will not include files or directories that were excluded by my p4 client spec.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `exclude` option with pathspecs.  For instance:

```
$ git log --first-parent --name-status -- ':(exclude)plugin/'
```

in a clone of the [syntastic repository](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) *doesn't* show [commit `69b0c3e85a319ad21f560d7b25524cf02921be82`](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/commit/69b0c3e85a319ad21f560d7b25524cf02921be82), while `git log` *without* the exclusion does show it.